# Swift , Apllication running on background on the emulator but not on the device

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, timer

I did this code in swift (2.0)

```
var timer: dispatch_source_t!
var a = 0
func startTimer() {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.timer", nil)
    timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) // every 60 seconds, with leeway of 1 second
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {
        self.a = self.a+1
       print( self.a)
    }
    dispatch_resume(timer)
}

func stopTimer() {
    dispatch_source_cancel(timer)
    timer = nil
}
```

the problem is that this code work well on the emulator , I see in the consol a number incrementing every second, and when I go the the home page of the emulator the number is still incrementing ,
On the device, the number stop incrementing as soon as we quit the application context .
so how can I make it keep incrementinf on the device ?

Answer (score 1):

By default iOS applications do not support background execution. You can start execute finite-length background tasks with `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` method or you have to enable special background modes like voip, location, remote notifications to run in background. (The use of those modes are reviewed by Apple when you submit app to Appstore)

More info: [Background execution documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

I agree that it is quite misleading that it works on simulator, when it is not supposed to.

Comment: thank you for this answer , but is there a way to execute my sample code on background with asking for user permission or something else ?

Comment: It is possible with `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`, but what that only to finish up some lengthy tasks before app goes into suspended mode. It is not meant to keep you app running for sake of it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ah ok ,I want to run a task that doesn"t have lenght , that runs all the time , so u are telling me that is not possible ??

Comment: It is only possible to do certain tasks in background I mentioned before.